# Samba between Ubuntu server 10.10 and Windows Vista, Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, samba

I have a linux box running Linux server ubuntu 10.10. I have installed Samba on this linux box and want to share files with my laptops which run Windows Vista home and Windows 7 home. 
  I have been struggling with the setup for almost a month but couldn't get it right. If I try to access share folder from Windows Vista, I get message

```
"Windows cannot access \\server_ip_address". 
Error code: 0x80070035. The network path was not found.
```

If I access from Windows 7, then after entering password to login I can see the list of share folders on Linux box. But if I click on a share folder, I get the same error message as above.

Tail /var/log/samba/log.windows7-pc I got the following message:

```
[2011/03/16 00:17:41.427238,  0] smbd/service.c:988(make_connection_snum)
canonicalize_connect_path failed for service sharemedia, path /root/sharemedia
```

Here is my setting in smb.conf
    [global]
    share modes = yes
    netbios name = Samba

```
workgroup = WORKGROUP

wins support = yes

encrypt passwords = true

[sharemedia]
comment = Tesing sharing using Samba
path=/root/sharemedia/
public = yes
valid users = samba_usr_name

; make sure all files are sensible permissions
create mask = 0660
force create mask = 0660
directory mask = 2770
force directory mask = 2770
directory security mask = 0000

; Normal share parameters          
read only = no
browseable = yes
writable = yes                     
guest ok = no
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try enable guest OK. Also are you accessing via IP or via a name?

Also, due to the funny permissions that can sometimes apply to /root, you should try another directory ie /home/someusers/sharemedia/.

This is only half a solution, I can't be sure what the problem is without further troubleshooting.

Comment: You're right. It's the problem with root permission. I created another folder under a regular user directory and it's working fine now. Thanks a lot.  Sorry I cannot vote your answer up. I accidentally migrated my question into serverfault (I don't know why they had that option) and it requires at least 15 reputation to vote up :( I don't know how to migrate back to stackoverflow

Comment: @chepukha Don't worry, I did it for you (vote up) :)

Answer (score 2):

I resolved my problem connecting my Windows 7 box to my Ubuntu samba (11.10).  I Had the "Windows cannot access" error (0x80070035 - the network path was not found" when trying to access the server (or share).  I tried a lot of things, but when it came down to what actually solved it (all other items reversed) it was the "Microsoft Network client: Digitally sign communications (always)" setting that was causing my problem.  Once it was disabled, I could see the shares and map the drive.

Answer (score 0):

Just for a test try to disable IPv6: [as described here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929852). Also see [ubuntuforums.org](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1439582).

Comment: I have disabled ipv6 on Ubuntu since I installed it. Windows 7 can access share folder now even with ipv6 available. Windows Vista however still have problem even after disabled ipv6. Thanks